# Custom UIProgressView with image

Tags: ios, progress-bar

I’m trying to make a custom UIProgressView where the image that gets filled up is the Nike Swoosh. I’ve tried to follow some tutorials but am getting nowhere.

My current approach:

Make the inside of swoosh transparent and surroundings black. 
Then put a big UIProgressView behind that. 
Since the middle of the swoosh is transparent, it looks like the swoosh is filling up.

But, modifying the height of the progress bar has proven to be a pain since it messes with the width in a weird way…and it’s hard to align the swoosh with the progress bar for responsiveness.

Are there any other ideas or libraries out there?

Thanks

Comment: Create your own control that draws the swoosh and fills it in as needed.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

draw a second image programatically to apply as a mask against your 'swoosh' image, and then repeat this cyclically.

example, fill image from left (mask it from right)

```
{
//existing variables

IBOutlet UIImageView *swooshView;


}

-(UIImage *)maskImageOfSize:(CGSize )size filledTo:(CGFloat )percentage{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions ( size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


CGContextSetFillColourWithColour (context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

CGRect fillRect = CGRectZero;
fillRect.size.height = size.height;
fillRect.size.width = size.width * percentage / 100.0;
fillRect.origin.x = (size.width - fillRect.size.width);

CGContextFillRect(context, fillRect);

UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return result;
}



-(void)fillSwooshToPercentage:(CGFloat )percentage{

percentage = ((CGFloat ) fmaxf ( 0.0 , (fminf (100.0, (float) percentage ) ) );
 // just policing a 'floor' and 'ceiling'...
swooshView.layer.mask = [self maskImageOfSize:self.swoosh.bounds.size filledTo:percentage];

}
```